# Ajax Table is not showing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I am creating ajax table from database. my Controller returning list of object but table is not creating on the page rather it shows json string.
Here is my ajax call and view:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h2>Real Time Values</h2>

<body>
<div>
    <table id="tbldata" class="tabledata">
        <tr>
            <th>Meter Number</th>
            <th>Current A</th>
            <th>Current B</th>
            <th>Current C</th>
            <th>Current N</th>
            <th>Current Avg</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.get(("ShowRealTimeValues", "RealTimeValues", function (data) {
            var row;
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                row += "<tr><td>" + v1.MeterNumber + "</td><td>" + v1.Current_A + "</td><td>" + v1.Current_B + "</td><td>" + v1.Current_C + "</td><td>" + v1.Current_N + "</td><td>" + v1.Current_Avg + "</td></tr>"
            });
            $("#tbldata").append(row);
        }))
    })
</script>

 </body>
```

Here is my controller. My controller is returning list of object.

```
   public ActionResult ShowRealTimeValues()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        var data = myDbContext.RealTimeValues.OrderByDescending(a => a.Time).Take(1).ToList();

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Dont know why table is not creating. there is not any error in console.

Comment: Why store the data in session ? why not build your table when you get a response from ajax ?

Comment: i feels convenient for me by storing data in sessions

Comment: But I believe that the problem here is that your foreach won't be trigger since the page didn't load.

Comment: i can see data in json format in page but can't know why tables are not showing....

Comment: i also tried creating table from ajax

Comment: If you really want to insist that foreach then you need create the data from your page load and not by ajax. There are tons of example how to do that.

Comment: For the next time please update and keep the "old" question and not modify totally thus the answers seem stupid.

Comment: sorry my mistake.. next time i'll

Answer (score 1):

You can not use session at the client-side. To manipulate the table you not even need to keep the data in session. A workaround can be

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ShowRealTimeValues", "RealTimeValues")',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            var theTable="<table id='yourTableId' class='yourTableClass'>";
            var theTr="";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                theTr = theTr + "<tr><td>" + result[i] + "</td></tr>";
            }
            theTable = theTable + theTr + "</table>";
            $(".tblContainer").empty();
            $(".tblContainer").html(theTable);
        }
        });

    <div class='tblContainer'>

    </div>
```

Comment: on page its showing :

{"Id":0,"MeterNumber":"EMREAL_1","Date":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Time":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Current_A":33.5,"Current_B":15.5,"Current_C":415.5,"Current_N":0.055,"Current_G":0,"Current_Avg":4456.5,"Voltage_A_B":0,"Voltage_B_C":0,"Voltage_C_A":0,"Voltage_L_L_Avg":0,"Voltage_A_N":0,"Voltage_B_N":0,"Voltage_C_N":0,"Voltage_N_G":0,"Voltage_L_N_Avg":0,"ActivePower_A":0,"ActivePower_B":0,"ActivePower_C":0,"ActivePower_Total":0}

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is impossible because of the lifecycle.

First of all the HTML page generated on server side after that you get an AJAX result but the HTML page has already fine so you cannot populate your table via Razor because it run different time.

In my opinion you should use JavaSript array instead of Session.

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ShowRealTimeValues", "RealTimeValues")',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
       var array= result
       var html='';
       for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
            html += '<tr><td>' + array[i].Property1+ 
                    '</td><td>' + array[i].Property2+ '</td></tr>';
       }
        $("#tbl").append(html);
    }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

if you have an object you can try this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ShowRealTimeValues", "RealTimeValues")',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
       var html='';
       html += '<tr><td>' + result.MeterNumber+'</td><td>' + result.Current_A+'</td></tr>';

        $("#tbl").append(html);
    }
    });
```

Comment: bro on my page result is :
{"Id":0,"MeterNumber":"EMREAL_1","Date":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Time":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Current_A":33.5,"Current_B":15.5,"Current_C":415.5,"Current_N":0.055,"Current_G":0,"Current_Avg":4456.5,"Voltage_A_B":0,"Voltage_B_C":0,"Voltage_C_A":0,"Voltage_L_L_Avg":0,"Voltage_A_N":0,"Voltage_B_N":0,"Voltage_C_N":0,"Voltage_N_G":0,"Voltage_L_N_Avg":0,"ActivePower_A":0,"ActivePower_B":0,"ActivePower_C":0,"ActivePower_Total":0}

Comment: No problem, As you can see this is a JSON Object so you do not have to use for loop. So -> html += '<tr><td>' + array[i].MeterNumber +  '</td><td>' + array[i].Current_A + '</td></tr>'; ...etc

Comment: Sorry I am totally stupid you can try out this ->  html += '<tr><td>' + result.MeterNumber + '</td><td>' + result.Current_A + '</td></tr>'; ...etc

Comment: i don't know why its not working..... i tried all things and also tried tutorial from youtube but still noting good. 
there not any error in console

Comment: Can you link a picture about the problem?

Comment: bro i have edited my question... kindly check... thanks alot

Comment: Please change your action return type to JsonResult.

Comment: please check i have uploaded

Comment: Firstly i'm sorry for late response. then i am very thankful for your time and good response obviously its working good from your end and also at this online compiler. but not working on my side. i have created new controller and paste all your code here but don't know why its not working for me. 
thanks alot for your time really.